# Relational database for tracking IPv6/IPv4 addresses -- will my proposed schema work?

Tags: sql, database, ipv6, ipv4

**Background**

I'm building an IPAM app to track and store metadata for individual IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. The backend is intended to be a boring, vendor-agnostic relational database.

IPv6 may deal with big numbers in a vast addressable space, but the scope in question does not inherently constitute big data, so I'm not willing to change backend architectures without some actual technical shortcoming of my current approach that is better served by a hip NoSQL solution at the expense of relations and ACIDity.

(I'm not trying to document the entire address space, only live addresses in use by arbitrary customers.)

**Schema**

Normalize the string representation of a given IP address and use that as the primary key. IPv4 addresses get converted to IPv6 and prefixed with `ffff`. IPv6 addresses get compressed and lowercased.

A second field indicates which protocol version the record in question is-- 4 or 6. The idea here is that if a user searches for records in an IPv4 subnet, I can quickly exclude the IPv6 space, or vice versa.

The next eight fields (ugh) are all integer representations of each octet in the address (`octet_1`, `octet_2`, etc.).

**Indexes**

Primary key should already be its own unique index.

Create an additional index on `(version, octet_1, ..., octet_8)`.

**Querying**

For searching for a specific IP of either version, I can simply normalize the IP string the same way as above and search through the primary keys.

For searching by subnet, the application calculates the start/end address for the range, casts both as IPv6, converts both to octuples, and issues a query for all records with octuples between those.

**What problems might I run into with this approach? Suggestions for improvement?**

Anything from `ipv4s casted as ipv6 are not the same thing` to `your index will explode / write performance will suck` is fair game.

I built a test POC which validates the functionality of this schema but I'm concerned about any potential shortcomings of this model in a production environment.

Comment: No need to "normalize" or anything similar. Just store the addresses in a column of type [inet](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET) - that's much more efficient than a string representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can choose database backend then go for PostgreSQL. It has built in types for IP addresses and therefore offers great performance and features.

But you said that you wanted to be database agnostic, so let's focus on that. In that case I would do just the string representation with IPv4 addresses prefixed with ::ffff:, but then use only lower case hexadecimal notation and no compression. So IPv4 address 10.11.12.13 would become 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a0b:0c0d.

Almost all databases have good indexing on strings, and with this notation you can easily do subnet and range queries. If you want all IPv4 addresses just query for LIKE '0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:%'. Because it's anchored at the start a standard btree index should work well. You can do more complex queries for ranges with < and > operators, which again can benefit from a standard index. That should give you most subnet queries.

In your application it shouldn't be too hard to parse the strings with inet_pton etc to convert them to whatever you need.

I'd avoid denormalising in this case. With what I described above you shouldn't need separate version or octet columns. They'll only slow things down and increase the chances of inconsistencies.

Comment: Interesting approach, I see the logic and it's certainly cleaner and easier to work with. Being strings though won't this result in much larger indexes and slower comparisons, or have databases gotten better at optimizing them? When I first started conventional wisdom was to compare, sort and index on integers and avoid strings wherever possible.

Comment: The problem is that most databases don't do 128 bit integers. PostgreSQL's inet/CIDR fields are a very useful exception. And a primary key consisting of multiple smaller integers will defeat the purpose, make querying for subnets that don't align with your field harder etc. Strings aren't ideal, but they are a useful compromise if you're not dealing with millions of records. And if you are you should optimize for a specific database anyway. In that case I'd choose PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Schema", you have not given an actual schema.

"IPv4 addresses get converted to IPv6 and prefixed with ..." betrays that you don't understand the intent and purposes of IPV6.

"IPv6 addresses get ... lowercased." betrays that you don't understand the distinction between value and representation of a value ("get lowercased" might affect a ***representation*** of a value but it will ***never*** affect ***the value itself***).

"if a user searches for records in an IPv4 subnet" betrays that you do not understand the separation of concerns the conceivers of the OSI 7-layer model had in mind when conceiving their model of networking communications.  "Searching for records" is not a function on the same layer as IP (v4/v6).

"Primary key should already be its own unique index." betrays that you don't understand relational data management.

Probably you'll feel like this is not an answer to your question, but actually it is.

Comment: While I did solicit criticism on a topic you are clearly more familiar with than me, based on the fact that you're bringing up OSI as a concern I think you might be assuming too much. I'm not writing router firmware or crafting packets, I'm writing a frontend to a key-value store where each key is an abstraction for an IP address so as to be queryable by its string representation or by its underlying value(s) depending on the query type. I understand the distinction-- abstracting it is literally the point of this application.

Comment: The question is about an IPAM application: IP Address Management. The question makes perfect sense in that context...

Comment: If you are "writing an application that does stuff for users and that stuff has something to do with IP-addresses", and you want advice on your design, then you should (a) spend a lot more effort explaining the business problem (it is that which determines the ***semantics*** -the business meaning- your data will need to carry) and (b) provide an actual schema.  You still haven't done either of those.